# Determining the exact one from all possible Jordan Canonical Forms of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, jordan-normal-form

Here  is  the  example  I  encountered **:**

A matrix $\ M\ $ $(5\times 5)$ is given  and  its  *minimal polynomial* is determined to be $(x-2)^3.$ So considering the two possible sets of elementary divisors $$\{ (x-2)^3,(x-2)^2\}\ \ and\ \ \{(x-2)^3,(x-2),(x-2)\}$$  we get two possible  Jordan Canonical forms  of the matrix , namely $J_1$  and  $J_2$ respectively. So $J_1$ has $2$ and $J_2$ has $3$ **Jordan Blocks.**

Now  we  are to determine the exact one from these two. From the original matrix $M,$ we determined the Eigen vectors  and $2$  eigen  vectors were *linearly independent.* So the result is that $J_1$ is the one .So, to determine the exact one out of all possibilities , we needed two information **-**

$1)$ the minimal polynomial ,together with $2)$ the number of linearly independent eigen vectors .

Now this was a question-answer  book  so  not much theoretical explanations are given . From the given result , I assume the  number of linearly independent eigen vectors -which is $2$ in this case - decided $J_1$ to be the exact one  because it has $2$ **Jordan Blocks.** So  the equation

**"Number of linearly independent eigen vectors$=$Number of Jordan Blocks"**

must be true for this selection to be correct .

Now this equation is not proved in this book or the  text book I have read  says  nothing of this sort .

So, that is  my question here **:** How  to  prove the equation **"Number of linearly independent eigen vectors$=$Number of Jordan Blocks"**
 $?$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a matrix reduced in Jordan form. Notice that for every Jordan block relative to the eigenvalue $\alpha$ there is an eigenvector with respect to $\alpha$ and these vectors ar independent. To see this just look at the first column of a generic block. So 
$\#$Jordan blocks$\le\#$independent eigenvectors. To prove the other inequality, consider the matrix $A-\alpha I$ for every eigenvalue $\alpha$ and calculate its rank.